# Microphone Not Working With FaceTime

Tags: iphone, facetime

I'm at a loss on this one. My girlfriends microphone is not working in FaceTime on her iPhone 5s. The microphone itself works because we tested it with the Voice Memos app. When we have a FaceTime conversation I can occasionally hear some sort of clicking/crackling noise, but no voice. I don't know exactly what it's picking up. However with strictly FaceTime audio calls it does pick up sound. The sound also does not work with voice recording text messages.

The first thing I thought of was thinking that maybe the app doesn't have permission to access the microphone. I looked though settings and on FaceTime but couldn't find where the permission could be toggled. And I had no idea how to force it to ask the permission question again.

Prior to getting her iPhone 5s screen fixed, she was using an old iPhone 4 for a long time. On the iPhone 4 FaceTime worked just fine. When she got the 5s back I restored it from iCloud with a backup image of the iPhone 4 so she would have all of her apps and what not. Since then the microphone on FaceTime has not been working.

Any tips or ideas on what to try?

Comment: You say the screen was recently fixed?  Apple, third party?  The crackling noise may be an indication that the phone was incorrectly reassembled or damage to the mic.  Odd though that it works with other apps.  The repair shop would be a good place to start.  Cheers.

Comment: @bjbk I had a friend of mine fix it who repairs Macs/iPhones. We checked to make sure the fingerprint sensor, mic, etc worked fine before leaving his house.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if the iPhone is somehow detecting a pair of headphones in the device only when the FaceTime is active for video calls?

Steps to take:

1. Reboot iPhone
2. Try in phone app
3. Try again with FaceTime

Possibly also try a device backup and then restore either using your computer or iCloud for the backup.

Edit:

When reading your comment, you reminded me that there are 2 separate mics on the iPhone 5S. [Microphones on iPhones](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203792). I believe the mic on the back is used for FaceTime and the front mic is used for phone calls as well as FaceTime Audio. Here is an [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/iPhone_5s) guide list for the iPhone 5S.

Comment: I found out that the 5s has two microphones and for whatever reason certain tasks use a specific microphone. I'm assuming the mic is damaged because the front camera and proximity sensor work fine. I'm going to reseat the cable to make sure it's not seater funky.

Comment: @DrZoo I just added some additional comments.

Answer (score 0):

Facetime Video using the front microphone (on the top in the earpice), while facetime audio using the bottom microphone.

You can try Phone Diagnostics (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/phone-diagnostics/id1171677218) to check all microphone on your iPhone.